# Audio PlaybackRate in mobile browsers and supported plugin

Tags: php, html, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I have to play a song in browses including **Android** and **iPhone**. I did it using the html5 audio player. But playbackrate is not working in **Mobile Browsers**. Is there any library or plugin available for this? Is **web-audio** API supports this feature?

In this [site](http://odogy.com/MusicShare/#620411) playback rate is working in mobiles too. But unable to find which method they are following?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <audio src="./audio/Kalimba.mp3" id="audio1"  controls>Canvas not supported</audio>
        <button id="playbutton" >Play</button>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            $('#playbutton').click(function () {
                var audioElm = document.getElementById("audio1");
                var playBackSpeed = 0.5;
                audioElm = document.getElementById("audio1");
                audioElm.playbackRate = playBackSpeed; // default speed 1
                audioElm.play();
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The site you're linking to uses Web Audio, but it doesn't use playbackrate to change the tempo of the song. Instead it schedules each note separately, so when you change the tempo, what you're really doing is change the BPM at which notes are scheduled. You can think of it as changing this:

```
setTimeout(schedule, 1000);
```

to:

```
setTimeout(schedule, 500);
```

when you go from 60 BPM to 120 BPM.

There is, however, a similar thing is Web Audio as what you're doing with the audio element. The AudioBufferSourceNode, which you use to play a pre recorded sample, has a property called playbackRate. This changes the rate of the audio (but doesn't do pitch correction!). Check it out at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode

Answer (score -1):

There are no any external Plugin or API which is required to play audio in Browser, this is one of the advantages of using HTML5.
Below i am mentioning the same with easy syntax and attributes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    </head>
   <body>
 <audio  controls>
<source src="Kalimba.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
  Audio not supported.
 </audio>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10797093)

Comment: What is exactly wrong with my solution. I executed the same on my browser and after getting the desired solution as wanted by the user, then only i posted it here.

Comment: Um...the OP already has an <audio> tag with the mp3 file...splitting the tag out to use the <audio> tag and the <source> tag is not any different...it simply allows for specifying multiple file formats.

Comment: If it is so, then give me a reason then, why it is not getting played by your side. Eventually i used the same with enhanced attributes, it get played at my side. What you missed it the "type" attribute that is it.

Comment: If it is so, then why it is not getting played at your side. Eventually i used the same one with enhanced attribute, it get played to my side.